# Blank space underneath background between footer (mobile only)

Tags: css, wordpress, html, mobile

As the title says, the issue arises only when viewed on mobile.

On my pc it looks exactly as desired but when I open it up on a mobile device there is a blank space between the background image and the footer?

Site is live @

https://claritysalonspa.com

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as the community won't go to live websites to debug code. You need to include the relevant code, what it should do and what it is currently doing. A screenshot of the inspector open of that element also helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are adding the background image in the backend, but try adding the following style. In here, `.page-id-29` is the class added to the current page, and you added a background image to it.

```
.page-id-29 {
    background-image: url(YOUR-IMAGE);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;                 // add the height
    background-position: 50% 50%;  // center the image
}
```

so the solution is to add `height: 100vh` and also change the image position so it is centered.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your style.css

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
.page-id-29{height: 95vh;}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `body`doesn't have enough `content`. If you add more content then there is no trick needed.

You can overcome this by adding `min-height` to your `body` tag.

```
.page-id-29 {
    background-image: url(https://claritysalonspa.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/IMG_5215.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 92vh; /* this for height */
    background-position: center center; /* to center the image */
}
```

If you want to make your footer always bottom of the `viewport`  please add thi also.

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0 !important; 
}
```